# NFC - Can i pass NdfMessage to iOS?

Tags: android, ios, nfc, ndef

I am developing an APP using NFC tech to pass some data to another android device

but can i pass NdfMessage to iOS device?

if an iOS device has external NFC chip

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no NFC chip on iOS devices... maybe on iPhone5 or external accessories

Comment: yes i mean the iOS device has external accessories, like a back shell, then the iOS device can receive data by nfc tech, so my problem is can i push NdefMessage to an iOS device when the iOS device has external accessories?

Comment: If you are using an external accessory is better you look at the spec and check how it communicate with the device.

Comment: So iOS doesn't have an open source SDK?